# More than one clone of xp qcow2 base image using kvm gives missing hal.dll error

Tags: linux, debian, kvm-virtualization, clone, qcow2

I am running linux mint debian edition.
I have kvm installed and working, using virt-manager as the manager. I have a qcow2 disk file with windows xp pro installed that I used as a base to clone a new qcow2 file.  I have done this before without a problem.  For testing I want to run multiple clones.  However, if I boot up more than one clone at a time I get the following error in Windows:

```
Windows could not start because the following file is missing or corrupt:
<Windows root>\system32\hal.dll.
Please re-install a copy of the above file.
```

This seems to happen with any combination of cloned qcow2 image based vm's that I run.  I can run any of them separately.  But, if I try to boot a second one when there's also one running off of the same base image, I get that error.

Should I be able to run multiple clones like I want for testing?  If so, please point me in the right direction to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your clones using the same writable image by any chance?
You need to provide a different image to every VM running concurrently.

Comment: Not really.  I am using a qcow2 read only base image with multiple clones.  See http://www.linux-kvm.com/content/how-you-can-use-qemukvm-base-images-be-more-productive-part-1.  Only the clone images get attached to the vm's.

Comment: If you're sure you're doing everything right, no idea. Try [mounting a cloned image](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Images#Mounting_an_image_on_the_host) while another VM is running and checking if the files are there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I wasn't able to mount it as a loop device.  According to what I found on google, you must mount a qcow2 device using qemu-nbd.  However, I wasn't able to get it mounted like that.  I instead attached it to another vm and booted to a livecd.  Sure enough, system32 was somehow missing.  I deleted the clone and recreated and now have two vm clones based on the same backing image running simultaneously.  Thanks!